Cannot get Nextjs 14 application serving under sub application in IIS
I have a basic Next 14 app that I am hosting under IIS website on the root that works fine. If I create a sub application off the root and move the application there, I get a 404 when browsing to root/subapplication.
My Server.js file looks like this
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const port = process.env.PORT || 3010;
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
    // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

    if (pathname === '/a') {
      app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
    } else if (pathname === '/b') {
      app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
    } else {
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
    }
  }).listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
})

And the web.config looks like:
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>    
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="myapp">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <iisnode node_env="production" nodeProcessCommandLine="&quot;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe&quot;" interceptor="&quot;%programfiles%\iisnode\interceptor.js&quot;" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />

  </system.webServer>
  <location path="" overrideMode="Deny">
      <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
           <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>
      </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>

I have tried following every article / post on this I can find and nothing is working. I have tried modifying my next.config.mjs to specify a supPath in various ways and none of those have worked.
What do I need to do to?

You didn't follow mine, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-next-js-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

@LexLi After following that, I am still getting a 404 when I browse to localhost/SubApplicationName. I have taken the web.config from that article and pointed at my local node.exe and modified next.config.mjs to include basePath: '/SubApplicationName'

You will have to completely dump iisnode and follow every steps of my post. The two approaches differ in many ways.

@LexLi Managed to get it working following your article. Previously was using IISnode module which required a bunch of rewrite rules and  aserver.js file, which I hadnt realised I no longer needed with HTPPlatformHandler. When I got rid of them it all started working

You can write/accept your own answer below then.

@LexLi - Coming back to this as have just discovered that when I navigate using Next Link component or router.push the full page is being requested every time once deployed to IIS. In the request headers there are no Next values such as next-router-state-tree so its getting the page as if I just did a hard refresh. Is there something connected to your solution that is stopping next intercepting and managing navigation?

I was able to get this working following Lex Li's blog post
https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-next-js-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/
Initially I had assumed that I still required my rewrite rule that forwarded requests to my server.js, but that was not the case and taking the web.config up from that article in full and ditching iisnode entirely fixed the problem. Adding the basePath value additionally allowed for static files to be requested from the correct URL.
